# convert sql server file into mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

how can i convert MSSQl file into mysql ... ?if it is not possible then please help me in this file..

here is my ms sql server file ..it has 4 tables

http://pastebin.com/VQVYpsHX

i want to know the relationship between the tables ... i am trying to make an eer model in a workbench but it gives me an error of using **non utf characters** so i think workbench support only mysql file ...

or if u cant convert it then tell me in plain english that what is the relationship between these four tables ... for example there is a many to many relationship b/w table 1 to table 2 like that

Comment: 263 lines of MSSQL code...I don't think anyone is going to convert all that for you here.

Comment: Get Microsoft SQL Server Express: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx and throw it in there.

Comment: @Jocelyn i am asking if there is anysoftware available.. i dont want someone to manually convert it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraint lines in you output may define the constraints, eg:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Message]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Message_Message] FOREIGN KEY([OpratorID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Oprator] ([ID])
```

says there is a relationship between `Message` and `Operator` ( `Message.OperatorID = Operator.ID` )